# How can i make one-to-many chat with ScriptCam?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-webcam-plugin

I would like to know how to make one-to-many chat, I search everywhere but there is no code ,tutorial or demo like in there website. have someone any idea how to make it?